# Passing few lambdas as parameter of method

Tags: java, lambda

I want to pass a few lambda methods as parameters to the method. Not one lambda, but few lambdas. How to do that?

```java
flines = arg -> arg.startsWith("WAW");

String fname = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/LamComFile.txt"; 

InputConverter<String> fileConv = new InputConverter<>(fname);

List<String> lines = fileConv.convertBy(flines);

String text = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join);

List<Integer> ints = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join, collectInts);

Integer sumints = fileConv.convertBy(flines, join, collectInts, sum);
    ...
```

Comment: If you mean passing multiple lambda arguments to a method, you can use multiple functional interfaces as the arguments of that method. What other than that does your question mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to write method which return type depends on `Function`-argument:

```
class InputConverter<T> {
   private final T value;

    public InputConverter(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <R> R convertBy(Function<T, R> function){
        return function.apply(value);
    }
 }
```

and then you can combine `Function`-arguments use standard methods `compose` and `andThen`:

```
final String fname = "fname_value"

InputConverter<String> inputConverter = new InputConverter<>(fname);

Function<String, List<String>> valueToListFunction = Arrays::asList;
Function<List<String>, String> firstValueFunction = l -> l.get(0);

List<String> strings = inputConverter.convertBy(valueToListFunction);//[fname_value]
String firstValue = inputConverter.convertBy(
            valueToListFunction
                    .andThen(firstValueFunction)
);
```

also you can use other standard `FunctionalInterfaces`, like `UnaryOperator`:

```
UnaryOperator<String> firstChangeFunction = arg -> arg.concat(" + first");
UnaryOperator<String> secondChangeFunction = arg -> arg.concat(" + second");

String firstValue = inputConverter.convertBy(
            valueToListFunction
                    .andThen(firstValueFunction)
                    .andThen(secondChangeFunction)
                    .compose(firstChangeFunction)
); // sout: fname_value + first + second
```

or write yourself.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I need to add function in arguments like this:
fileConv.convertBy(flines, join, collectInts);. How to do that?

Comment: You can use ``variable-length argument``, like ``fileConv.convertBy(Function<T, ?>... f)``, but this approach is a bit anclear and inconvenient. I thin it is a bad practice...